# How to remove a directory with "Too many levels of symlinks"

Tags: symlink

I have a bit of an odd problem on a RHEL system.

On our systems we have our home directory automounted under `/export/home`. There are a few exceptions, as I'm experimenting with using gluster for our home dirs. These are automounted under `/gluster/home`

This works on all our (30+) servers. Today this stopped working on one of them. I get the error:

```
Too many levels of symlinks
```

when trying to `cd` into `/gluster/home/$HOME`...

I ended up temporary moving `/gluster` to `/gluster_broken`, and made a new `/gluster/home`, restarted autofs and things work again.

Now I want to remove `/gluster_broken`.

The problem is that aparently there is some symlink loop in `/gluster_broken/home`. I don't know where it came from. My attempts to get rid of it have been fruitless so far.

```
[root@dc1-03 /]# rm -rf gluster_broken/
rm: cannot remove `gluster_broken/home': Too many levels of symbolic links
[root@dc1-03 /]# rm -rf /gluster_broken/
rm: cannot remove `/gluster_broken/home': Too many levels of symbolic links
[root@dc1-03 /]# rm -rf /gluster_broken/home/
rm: cannot remove `/gluster_broken/home/': Is a directory
[root@dc1-03 /]# rm -rf /gluster_broken/home
rm: cannot remove `/gluster_broken/home': Too many levels of symbolic links
[root@dc1-03 /]# rmdir /gluster_broken/home/
rmdir: failed to remove `/gluster_broken/home/': Device or resource busy
[root@dc1-03 /]# fuser -m /gluster_broken/home/
Cannot stat /gluster_broken/home/: Too many levels of symbolic links
Cannot stat /gluster_broken/home/: Too many levels of symbolic links
Cannot stat /gluster_broken/home/: Too many levels of symbolic links
[root@dc1-03 /]# ls -ld /gluster_broken/home/
ls: cannot access /gluster_broken/home/: Too many levels of symbolic links
[root@dc1-03 /]# ls -ld /gluster_broken/home
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Jan 22 10:20 /gluster_broken/home
[root@dc1-03 /]# fuser -m /gluster_broken/home
```

As you can see most commands all yield the same error message. I would really like to get rid of this problem. But I'm a bit at a loss here. Any suggestions?

Output of suggested commands:

```
[root@dc1-03 /]# ls /gluster_broken/
home
[root@dc1-03 /]# ls /gluster_broken/home/
ls: cannot access /gluster_broken/home/: Too many levels of symbolic links
[root@dc1-03 /]# ls -hblF /gluster_broken /gluster_broken/home 
/gluster_broken:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Feb  4 12:00 home/
ls: cannot open directory /gluster_broken/home: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Comment: A bit of a guess/hack, but what if you mount something to gluster_broken/home  then try to `rm -rf gluster_broken` ?

Comment: An obvious question, but what does gluster_broken contain? Can you give a listing?

Comment: How is `/gluster_broken/home` mounted (as seen in /proc/mounts)?

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -hblF /gluster_broken /gluster_broken/home`

Comment: What does `namei /gluster_broken/home` say?

Comment: Tried the suggestions, and a few others. Almost any command that tries to do something with /gluster_broken/home throws the same error... Added the output to my question.

Comment: despite the ´d´ special file designation this `home` doesn't look like a "normal directory", the smallest size for a directory seems to be 4096 bytes for ext4 (the inode size, I suppose), perhaps this question is related: http://serverfault.com/q/232093/165677

Comment: Also, can you show the relevant part of the output of `mount | column -t`?

Comment: @KristvanBesien let me know when you post this

Comment: I think there  are no symlinks involved here; there is an actual  loop in the filesystem structure due to some mounting setup. Only, the OS is reporting it that way using the errno code `ELOOP`. The usual assumption in Unix is that since cycles in the dir structure itself are forbidden, the only way name lookup can cycle is via symlinks.  So the `ELOOP` errno constant is given a piece of text (by the `strerror` function in user space) about too many symlinks.  The errno texts are often vague, or not quite an accurate description of the situation for which they are used.

Comment: Time for a `gluster` `fsck`.

Answer (score 5):

Try find.

```
find -L /gluster_broken -mindepth 10
```

to find the link loops

then a non recursive `rm` on the erroneous file(s)

find will follow links and find the same "too many levels" error. I use -mindepth to filter out anything less than 10 deep to avoid the ok files/directories. Yes, this does  assume that you don't have more that 10 deep in your normal tree. All this command is trying to do is find the file in error.

-- edit

I think following command is better,

```
find -L /gluster_broken >/dev/null
```

Here's my test

```
$ find .
.
./dira
./dira/a
./dira/dirb
./dira/dirb/dirc
./dira/error
./dira/b
./dira/test
./dira/test/ab&<cd.file
./dira/test/magic?newlines
./dira/test/cleanup
$ find -L . >/dev/null
find: ‘./dira/a’: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: ‘./dira/error’: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: ‘./dira/b’: Too many levels of symbolic links
$
```

--- edit 2

I think my suggestion (comment) to check file-system might be best, I have just seen [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/599498/nfs-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links-how-to-find-and-fix#answers-header) and wonder if you have a similar issue.

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: Oops there's a typo `-maxdepth 10` shouldn't be there. I'll edit.

Comment: My problem is that about anything that somehow tries to do something with /gluster_broken/home throws this "to many levels of symbolic links" error. The "find" command suggested above does throw this error too, so I am not getting any usefull info out of it.

Comment: I think that /gluster_broken/home is looping on to itself. I would like to know however how this happened, and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Would be so interesting to see output of `ls -l /gluster_broken` .

Comment: ls -l /gluster_broken just shows me that it contains the directory home. ls -k /gluster_broken/home complains about the many levels of symlinks...
I think the problem must be that home is a symlink on itself. I don't have a clue how it could happen. But how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried a file-system check ? Also check you don't have anything mounted  there (/mount ). A system reboot is a sledgehammer approach but ensures you are at a known point.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems no one else answered the question.

The issue is that you have the `/` at the end of your command.

Instead of

```
rm gluster/
```

just run

```
rm gluster
```

By putting the `/` at the end you are attempting to go into the directory, which is a circular link, so it never finds the bottom. Without the `/`, you are simply removing the symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this same problem when creating a symlink without giving it an absolute directory.

This gave the same error when trying to read the file ("Too many levels of symlinks"):

```
ln -s ./config ~/.config/terminator
```

Seemingly because the symlink tries to go back on itself:

```
ls -l ~/.config/terminator
lrwxrwxrwx 1 zane zane 8 Dec 22 16:14 config -> ./config
```

But this worked:

```
ln -s /home/zane/config ~/.config/terminator/config
```

Hopefully, this will help someone in the same situation.

Comment: Yes, but here we see the symlink object.

Answer (score 0):

You cant remove /gluster_broken/home becouse /gluster_broken is a broken link itself.

```
ls -l  /gluster_broken
```

you will see it is a link. So remove it:

```
rm /gluster_broken
```